# Not a valid jar

Tags: r, hadoop, rhdf5, rmr2

I am new to R Programming.

I am using below code after setting all env variables. All connections are working well but I am getting an error in executing below of **to.dfs**.

Please guide me.

```
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_CMD"="/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop")
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_CONF"="/usr/local/hadoop/conf")
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_STREAMING"="/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tool/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar")

library(rhdfs)
hdfs.init()
library(rmr2)
library(plyrmr)
hdfs.ls('/user/hduser/')

sample <- 1:500

small.ints <- to.dfs(sample)
```

I am getting the error:

> Not a valid JAR: /usr/local/hadoop/share sh: 2:
>   hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar: not found

Comment: `to.dfs` is not a base R command - please edit your code to show which libraries you are using, so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: See this GitHub Issue with the [`rmr2`](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rmr2) package:

 [to.dfs sample does not work](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rmr2/issues/86)